# Bug related to an add role command on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this command I made with a Discord bot in Python. Basically, it's an event where it gives you a `Saloon Member` role when you write `givemembership` this command has been working on some of my test servers but sometimes simply didn't (I always gave the bot the admin perms). When it didn't work, the logs of the bot were saying the following:

[image]

Could someone maybe explain to me why it is not working ?
Here's the command programm.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "givemembership":
        member = message.author
        role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Saloon Member")
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i75164076/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the `Saloon Member` role above the bot role in the server roles? The `Forbidden` error implies the bot doesn't have permissions - so I would make sure that the bot's role (or a role that the bot has) is always above the role you want it to be able to assign. Otherwise it won't have the necessary perms.

Comment: That indeed wa the problem, thank you for your help ! @ESloman

Comment: No worries! I added it as an answer - when you can then you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Forbidden error implies the bot doesn't have permissions - so I would make sure that the bot's role (or a role that the bot has) is always above the role you want it to be able to assign. Otherwise it won't have the necessary perms.